# Python function only works when printing

Tags: python

This is code that creates unix credentials for sftp auth. I notice weird symptoms where if I run in a terminal, everything works and it outputs username and password that work over sftp. But if I remove the two lines "print(stdout.read())", then the functionality doesn't completely work. The account gets set up but password does not authenticate. Not sure if it's a problem with the "chpasswd" line.

What could a problem where not actually printing out stdout could cause code to fail (even though it appears to work fine and does not hit exception)?

These are the lines I am concerned about:

```
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' {}".format(ftp_username))
    print(stdout.read())
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("echo '{}:{}' | chpasswd".format(ftp_username, new_pass))
    print(stdout.read())
```

And this is the entirety of the code:

```
def create_user(ftp_username):
    client = connect_paramiko()

    new_pass = passgen.passgen()
    appendSSH = '''

    Match User {}
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
     PasswordAuthentication yes
     ChrootDirectory /var/sftp7/{}
     PermitTunnel no
     AllowAgentForwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     X11Forwarding no
         '''.format(ftp_username, ftp_username)

    client.exec_command("mkdir -p /var/sftp7/{}/{}".format(ftp_username, ftp_username))
    client.exec_command("chown root:root /var/sftp7/{}".format(ftp_username))
    client.exec_command("chown root:root /var/sftp7")
    client.exec_command("chmod 755 /var/sftp7/{}".format(ftp_username))
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' {}".format(ftp_username))
    print(stdout.read())
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("echo '{}:{}' | chpasswd".format(ftp_username, new_pass))
    print(stdout.read())
    client.exec_command("chown {}:{} /var/sftp7/{}/{}".format(ftp_username, ftp_username, ftp_username, ftp_username))
    client.exec_command("echo '{}' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config".format(appendSSH))
    client.exec_command("systemctl restart sshd")
    client.exec_command("usermod {} -d /{}".format(ftp_username, ftp_username))

    return {"username":ftp_username, "password":new_pass
```

And:

```
def connect_paramiko():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('...', username='root', key_filename='/root/.ssh/id_rsa')
    return client
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you provide the stack trace ?

Comment: @RishikeshJha as mentioned, it does not error and does not hit exception. Both times it looks to execute fine, but if I exclude the print statements, then the newly created unix user does not authenticate with that password. If i put the print lines back in, everything works fine.

Comment: I would guess, but I no nothing about `connect_paramiko()` Normally if you deal with pipes and `stdout` you need to `read()` from.. If there is no one attached to read, the process never writes and might be blocked in the I/O call (to write)... and then your whole script finishes and takes its children (including calls to other programs) with it. In other words... if you want to keep the code as is... try sill reading the `stdout`, but either assign it to a var, or just discard it. If that helps, I am likely on a right track. If not, I've tried. :)

Comment: Oh, if right on the previous comment the other option would seem to be, since those `.exec_command` methods seem to support it would be to redirect the output (to a file or `/dev/null`).

Comment: i have added in the code so you can see what connect_paramiko does

Comment: What does the print statements output on the screen?

Comment: @OndrejK. i think you are on the right track. i haven't had any success sending to /dev/null but if i assign a random test variable like "test" = stdout.read(), then that seems to work.

Answer (score -2):

The First Line, it's simply creating the user without any password

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' {}".format(ftp_username))
print(stdout.read())
```

In Second Line, we `echo username:password`, the result is passed to command `chpasswd`. This is done because when you will run the command `chpasswd` it will ask for `username:password`. So if we pass the result of echo `username:password` to `chpasswd` command it won't ask for the further input.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("echo '{}:{}' | chpasswd".format(ftp_username, new_pass))
print(stdout.read())
```

**More**

Just open your terminal and first of all you must to run the following command:

```
man adduser
```

With a little bit of luck you will find out that. Then, in that manual page type: **/--disabled-login** followed by **Enter** then press repetitively n to find all occurrences containing **--disabled-login.** Do the same for **--gecos**.

With a little bit of luck you will find out that:

```
--disabled-login
          Do not run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able 
          to use  her  account until the password is set.
```

Comment: Is this an answer? What is the solution? It just explains what I have unless I am missing something.

Comment: I just told you what are those two lines of code doing. Without knowing what your code is doing how can you expect it to work according to you. I am Still confused why are you removing those two lines of code.

Comment: So why does the code not work when I remove the print lines?

Comment: did you read the answer, that's what I wrote. Those to lines are used to set up login and password for the user. The first line make sure no password is set and second line sets the password manually.

Comment: This is not an answer.